# Jetpack Compose - how to center text in ClickableText

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

In Jetpack Compose, when using `Text`, we can center text using `TextAlign`:

```
Text(
    text = "How many cars are in the garage",
    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
)
```

But if we're looking to get the position of a click within a Text composable, we use `ClickableText`:

```
ClickableText(
        text = AnnotatedString("Click Me"),
        onClick = { offset ->
            Log.d("ClickableText", "$offset -th character is clicked.")
        }
    )
```

However I don't see how to center text in ClickableText? I can use gravity, but that will only center the component, not the text inside of it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can define the `textAlign` in the `style` parameter:

```
ClickableText(
    text = AnnotatedString("Click Me"),
    style = TextStyle(
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center),
    onClick = { offset ->

    }
)
```

Comment: In case someone has a similar situation, text already had a style so I added it like this: `style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2 + TextStyle(textAlign = TextAlign.Center)`

Comment: @haart You can use `style.merge(TextStyle(textAlign = textAlign))`

Comment: @haart You can also use `style.copy(textAlign = TextAlign.Center)` to override the textAlign property. just another option.